# What does 'left off at' mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What does 'left off at' mean here in 2 different sentences? Is it to mean just 'finish'?

> At the Academy Awards show, also known as the Oscars, talk of the
>   #MeToo movement continued where it **left off at** the Golden Globes.

Another sample:

> I think we **left off at** me awkwardly fleeing your apartment.

Comment: [Please cite your sources](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/36187). In general, it can be helpful in case you don't provide enough context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **leave off** (intransitive) means "to stop (temporarily, for the time being)".

> Do you remember where we left off in the bedtime story last night?
>   -- Yes. Little Red Riding Hood said "What big eyes you have, grandmother!"
>
> Sorry for that interruption. That was the CEO on the phone. Please continue where we left off. You were telling me about the internship you had last summer.

Answer (score 1):

### "Left off" means "stopped" or "paused", and is generally used in the context of resuming the activity that had been paused.

There's a bit of subtlety in the first example, though.  The quote does not mean to imply that talk about #MeToo literally stopped after the Golden Globes and didn't resume until the Oscars.  The author is trying to emphasize the continuity between the talk at the two events, while implying that there haven't been any major changes in what people are saying in the meantime.

The second example is more straightforward.  The people involved were doing something (probably having a conversation, but not necessarily), which ended unresolved when the speaker fled the apartment.